# How do I count the number of image request made by one particular site to my site

Tags: php, database, request

I have uploaded a image to my server and it is being used requested by many other multiple websites. I want to track the number of image request made by a particular site along with the ip address of the user who views the image. Is this possible? If yes, How can I do so ?

Comment: I would suggest looking at access logs rather than using PHP to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to let them access the image through a PHP script rather then giving them direct access to the file.

This way your can have the images in a directory that is not accessible to the clients.

Your script would be called like: *image.php?file=image.jpg*

Pseudo code of *image.php*:

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];

get_user_info_and_push_to_database();  // see $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

load_file_and_send_file_to_user();   // see header() and readfile()
```